# Make a PNG into a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

so I have a pattern as a PNG. I was wondering if Blender had a way of turning the PNG into a mesh. It's kinda like how if you put a transparent shader on a plane with an image texture you get a 2d picture/sprite thing. I was wondering if I could do something like that but extrude it so it's a 3d mesh. If any of that made sense, how could I do this/is there a way to do this without modelling it all over?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible without manually modelling it as far as I am aware. Would be a really cool addon though!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise just found it out! There's a type of pixture called .svg or something which can be turned into a mesh!

Comment: **TRACE**your image into paths using Inkscape or illustrator and save it as SVG. Then just import into blender using the SVG importer. Make sure you read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/svg-to-mesh-conversion

Comment: @Chickenator True, SVG files do that, however with PNG files (like you asked) there is no way to do that.

Comment: See the answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/tracing-a-monochrome-image-into-a-3d-extruded-object-with-a-script/1610#1610

Comment: Can you post an example of your image?

Comment: @ajwood no I can't because I haven't made it yet, it's just an idea

Comment: @Chickenator even a scribbled idea would be helpful. Something like this (http://img27.fansshare.com/pic19/w/seamless3d/1200/21569_seamless_texture_of_star_shape_with_complex_colorful_pattern.jpg) will probably need a different strategy from this (http://4vector.com/i/free-vector-beautiful-pattern-background-03-vector_015044_all-free-download.com_109363670.jpg)

Comment: @ajwood okay, here's an image if you need one http://imgur.com/prLCAAS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a possibility I have thought of:

Create a plane. Subdivide it a lot. Then add displacement modifier. Make sure the texture is black and white.

Apply the texture to the displacement modifier, this will raise 1 area of the plane while the other is lowered. Apply the displacement modifier.

Than you can go to side view in edit mode and select the lower faces using box select and delete them.

Comment: I guess that could work, if my computer can handle all the vertices