# How do I turn my PNG Image into a mesh object?

Tags: mesh, import, image, extrude

I am new to Blender. I have a PNG image of a logo and would like to know how to make this 2D image into a 3D image in Blender so that I can animate it like any ordinary mesh object that I can add into the 3D workspace. In addition, I would also like to know how to add color in Blender so that it will look exactly like it is in the image.

Thank you!

Here is the PNG image of the logo.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a PNG into a mesh?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/make-a-png-into-a-mesh)

Answer (score 2):

If you want in to be well done import the image as a viewport background image and manually trace over it using a bezier curve object.

If you are more comfortable working with applications using an illustration workflow like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), you can manually trace it using a pen tool and then export/import as an SVG.

Alternatively, you you want a faster method Inkscape also has a builtin image tracer that can trace a raster file and create the corresponding vector automatically but the quality some times leaves a lot to be desired and your mileage may vary.