# export to mesh particles and alpha-powered texture

Tags: mesh, particles, export, sapling-addon

I have a scene of nature with grass (particles), trees (sapling and particles) and I want to export the scene to mesh files (obj, ply or similar) with corresponding color value. Here are some problems that I have:

- grass particle cannot be exported
- the leaves (modeled as planar object with alpha-powered texture) are all exported as rectangles. I want them to be planes but with shapes of leaves
- the color are not matched, the trees are all green?
- I also want to export the corresponding pass index of each object as well

Comment: You can't really expect a texture based leaf to export as geometry.

Comment: I kinda expect the same thing. Do you have any idea to work around? Maybe I should ask another question on how to cut a plane into a leaf-shape given a leaf image with alpha channel?

Comment: Maybe you should search first, in all likelihood someone as already asked it before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/is-it-possible-to-give-a-texture-thickness or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/make-a-png-into-a-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object