# Design of Pen holder with musical score

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I’m again here to ask your support. I’d like to draw a 3d-print someting similar to “[tower of pi](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:271769)” but instead of using numbers, I’d like to use a musical score, let’s say beethoven fifth symphony.

I have a picture (B/W image) of what I need:

[image]

I would “extrude” black portion of musical score, wrapped around a cilindrical shape.

Is there some way to use a displace modifier in order to use mi musical score to be wrapper around a spiral?

Thank you very much as usual!
Francesco

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23411/make-a-png-into-a-mesh

Comment: If the goal is 3d printing you might want to try tracing the image on a vectorial graphics program (like inkscape or illustrator), conveting the bitmaps to paths and saving as SVG. Then import the SVGs into blender and bend them using a curve or bend modifier

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used inkscape and vonverted, I'll update my post with result of my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick go.

Took the source image into **GIMP** and made it one long line.

Imported that image into **Inkscape** and used ***Path/Trace Bitmap*** to create the vector data, then saved as **SVG**. See notes at the end.

Used import from the ***File*** menu in **Blender**
[image]

Then extruded the curve. I also converted the curve to a **Mesh** and used the **ReMesh Modifier** to stop some bad geometry where vertices where connected from great distance.

From the ***User Preferences*** view I searched for **Extra** and selected the **Curve: Extra Objects**
[image]

Now I could add a new **Curve** and select the type **Spiral** and **Logarithmic**. Set the **height** and the **number of turns** to create the spring shape.

In the **Curve** panel ensure the **Twisting** is set to **Tangent**. This ensures the results do not twist as they are modified by the spiral. Without this you get an unpeeled orange effect.
[image]

Now you can add a **Curve modifier** and select the **Spiral**.
[image]

The final result.
[image]

Notes:
The image was not particularly high resolution and made the initial vector data quite messy.

I needed to remesh the curve to get the vertices density required to allow the curve to take place.

There are lots of disconnected pieces, not ideal for 3D printing.

My basic result has obvious sharp ends that would need additional work to create a clean cylinder.

Suggest you take a lot of time to create nice neat/clean vectors before trying to extrude/curve.