# Invert knife tool cut or other tool to use

Tags: modeling, workflow, image

I am trying to cut out a rough outline of the background image to hopefully make a 3D Model of it as seen in the screenshot below.
[image]

Originally I used the knife tool but that tool only cuts OUT the cuts (the outside) and not cuts out the inside. So in a way I want to use the knife tool to trim my cube more and more until I have a model of my background image.

Any help or ideas? Is there a way to cheat and make a rough model from the background image?
How would I achieve my goal with the knife tool?
Is there another tool I should use instead?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/tracing-a-monochrome-image-into-a-3d-extruded-object-with-a-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trace your object as SGV and import it to blender. Once it blender it will be a series of curves that you can manipulate as you want.

[image]

For a tutorial on using inkscape to do this porcedure watch
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ows2QTiMRPg

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! This helped me a ton with my project.

Answer (score 4):

I would extrude a single vertex around, *building* the model up instead of *cutting* it out.

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can be used to extrude and position geometry in one step, or <kbd>E</kbd> can be used for a two step extrude and move.

[image]

---

That said you might get a similar result much more easily if you auto-trace the image into a vector SVG with a program such as [inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace), then import the SVG into blender.